# Heroku's recommendation to replace session stickiness?

Tags: session, heroku

We have a legacy java webapp which we'd like to migrate to Heroku. It uses session stickiness, which is unfortunately forbiddn on Heroku - so we wonder what's the Heroku recommended alternative ?

We're aware that if server crashes, it loses data stored on its sessions. But our sessions held only non-critical data... mostly, ShoppingCart for a user that isn't logged in (login may be postponed until the payment stage). Stickiness was fine for this, except for rare occasions of crashes - we could live with that.

On Heroku we need another solution, and all my ideas so far - seem a bit ugtly...

(1) I considered session replication, but it's bad for performance especially on large number of dynos

(2) I considered storing ShoppingCart in an external data storage (e.g. database). But how would I know which cart belongs to which user? Recall user isn't logged in, so I can't find the Cart by username. I'll have to assign some temporary name, which would actually mimic session behavior: send it to the browser as a cookie (so that it will identify further requests from the same client), remember to clean it after some idle time.

I feel I'm missing Heroku's design intent, because my code is becoming uglier instead of cleaner... are there better solutions please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `--session-store` feature of `webapp-runner`. See https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner#store-your-sessions-in-memcache. You can get a memcached instance attached to your app via several Heroku add-ons. Redis is also supported as a session store.

If you are using the .war deployment and don't have a Procfile, Heroku still uses `webapp-runner` under the covers and allows you to set the session store via `WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#advanced-options.

You won't be able to perform 'traditional' replication, because 1) where the app runs is dynamic and unpredictable and 2) the dynos won't be able to listen on anything other than HTTP ports.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, be aware of the standard session gotcha - all your objects in HttpSession will need to be serializable. This also comes into play if you ever need scale to multiple dynos: your user will be bounced between them (no session affinity in Heroku). You can emulate multiple dynos locally with Foreman (installed with the tool belt), a Procfile, and a local "load balancer" - Apache or Nginx are both relatively easy to configure in this capacity.